# How to get actual x and y of control position c#

Tags: c#, winforms, panel

I have a button inside a panel control . When I set scrolls to (0,0) the button top(y) and left(x) positions are returned correct, but when I scroll the button y and x are returned with respect to scroll . How to get accurate x and y even when panel is scrolled ?

```
public void call()
{
    MessageBox.Show(button1.Left+","+button1.Top);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have changed your code so it shall give you same coordinates irrespective of scroll position, (but its dependent on scrollable control, in this case panel)

```
MessageBox.Show((button1.Left + this.panel1.HorizontalScroll.Value)+ "," + (button1.Top + this.panel1.VerticalScroll.Value));
```

Comment: Anchor is putting the button fixed to one position according to the size of parent. As the button is moveable (can be set to be dragged in panel anywhere) , the anchor is not option. Any other way and thanks for reply ?

Comment: @phpnet, Yes, anchor will set the distance  from the parent's edge as fixed.  As you have mentioned that the button is movable. then you are actually changing its X & Y coordination for it to move, they will certainly not be (0,0) after re-positioning the button. So in my opinion, your code is giving you the actual X & Y . Are you looking for a way to en-cache  design time X & Y coordinates ? Please write me a comment if you think I have misunderstood you.

Comment: (0,0) is the scroll position of panel not the button and no I am looking for the runtime coordinates

Comment: @phpnet, I now understand your point... I have changed my answer. Does this changed code serve your purpose.